# Is it possible to modify AWS Cognito user attributes in the Lambda triggers

Tags: triggers, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Having a look at the AWS documentation,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-signup

you have the following paramaters available in the  ***Pre Sign-up*** Lambda fuction:

```
"request": {
  "userAttributes": {
    "string": "string",
    ....
},
"validationData": {<validation data as key-value (String, String) pairs, from the client>}
```

is there a way to modify or add additional ***userAttributes*** the the event object?

for example:

```
// Modify an existing username...
event.request.userAttributes.name.ucfirst();

// Add an additional attribute...
event.request.userAttributes.nickname = "ANY_NAME";


callback(null, event);
```

Comment: Hello @dieheld, Have you found solution for this problem?

Comment: I ran into the same question. I looks like there is no way to modify the user attributes except for the three - `event.response.autoConfirmUser`, `event.response.autoVerifyEmail`, and `event.response.autoVerifyPhone` which can be done in Pre Signup, but none of the `custom:` ones can be modified. None of the trigger hooks support updating `custom:` user attributes afaik and based on my tests. This could be a highly desirable feature.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, there's absolutely a way! You need to use AWS javascript SDK in your Lambda handler:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-1'});

const cognitoidentityserviceprovider =
  new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
    apiVersion: '2016-04-18'
  });
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminUpdateUserAttributes(
  {
    UserAttributes: [
      {
        Name: 'YOUR_USER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME',
        Value: 'YOUR_USER_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE'
      }
    ],
    UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
    Username: event.userName
  },
  function(err, data) {
    ...
  }
);
```

Make sure to give your Lambda function the right policies (i.e. allows "cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes" action) and the user pool has the attribute defined.

Comment: This doesn't work for me within the Pre-signup function; it looks like the user isn't created at this point. Did anyone else get it to work?

Comment: This seems to intermittently fail in the post confirmation trigger too due to the user not existing yet (when using federated identities for sign up)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is: is there a way to modify or add additional userAttributes the the event object?

Comment: Works for me, the additional attribute must be defined in schema ("custom:propertyName"), here is another reference from aws https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminUpdateUserAttributes-property

Answer (score 11):

There isn't a way to mutate/augment attributes during sign up, but during sign in, you can mutate/augment them with the [pre-token generation trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-token-generation).

Comment: I suspect this is the correct answer, because none of the other solutions work for me.

Comment: Does it work for SAML identity provider as well? I have noticed that, changes in the SAMLResponse attributes, doesnt update the user attribute in user pool.

Comment: This will only change the identity token administered by Cognito. When using for example `authorizer.context.fooBar` in API Gateway for example, this will not have your changes you have made, so you have to be careful doing that.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question as well. Thanks in advance!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68367111/get-login-confirmation-after-successful-login-aws-cognito

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else looking into insight on this question, here is an example below

The lambda function #1 below takes into two custom attributes `ida` and `ethaddress`. The lambda is invoked during the PreSignUpHook for Cognito user pools

#2 (Before event changed logs) the original values for these attributes is `ida=1` and `ethaddress=ABCD`

#3 (After event changed logs) reflects the changed values of these attributes:
`ida=2` and `ethaddress=EFGH`

However the values which are saved to cognito are the original ones: `ida=1` and `ethaddress=ABCD`. Therefore updateing the userAttributes during the presignuphook does NOT work as suggested in some of the answers.

On a side note when the predefined attributes in the response object are modified they are updated as expected:

```
"response": {
    "autoConfirmUser": true,
    "autoVerifyEmail": false,
    "autoVerifyPhone": false
}
```

1. LAMBDA:

```
'use strict';
global.fetch = require('node-fetch')

module.exports.preSignUp = async (event, context, callback) => {
// Set the user pool autoConfirmUser flag after validating the email domain

let data = await fetch("http://***.***.***/api/members/create",
{
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => res);

event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
console.log('before event:', JSON.stringify(event)); 
event.request.userAttributes['custom:ethaddress'] = String(data.address); 
event.request.userAttributes['custom:ida'] = "2";  
console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event));  
console.log('Address:', data.address);


 // Return to Amazon Cognito
callback(null, event);
 };
```

2.

BEFORE EVENT CHANGE LOG:

```
2019-01-20T01:02:24.639Z    edce636e-75ea-492b-b6a0-dd4f22dc9038    before event:
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "us-east-1-*****",
    "userName": "*******@gmail.com",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "******************"
    },
    "triggerSource": "PreSignUp_SignUp",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "custom:ida": "1",
            "custom:ethaddress": "ABCD",
            "email": "*******@gmail.com"
        },
        "validationData": {}
    },
    "response": {
        "autoConfirmUser": true,
        "autoVerifyEmail": false,
        "autoVerifyPhone": false
    }
}
```

3 .

AFTER EVENT CHANGE LOG:

```
Received event:
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "us-east-1_0BaE6eaTY",
    "userName": "*******@gmail.com",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "*****************"
    },
    "triggerSource": "PreSignUp_SignUp",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "custom:ida": "2",
            "custom:ethaddress": "EFGH",
            "email": "*******@gmail.com"
        },
        "validationData": {}
    },
    "response": {
        "autoConfirmUser": true,
        "autoVerifyEmail": false,
        "autoVerifyPhone": false
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

It seems like there is no way to do this as a part of the PRESIGNUP process
However it is possible to do this as a POSTCONFIRMATION trigger in cognito example provided below.

Some things to watch out for.

1. the custom attribute has added in cognito and is mutable.
2. in App client --> show details --> "Set attribute read and write permission"
   Ensure there is below read and write perms on the custom attribute.
3. Ensure that the lambda function has a ROLE which allows it to execute: adminUpdateUserAttributes
   E.g. Attach AmazonCognitoPowerUser Policy to the LambaRole.

```
module.exports.postConfirmation = async (event, context,callback) => {
        const cognitoIdServiceProvider = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
          region: 'us-east-1'
        });

        var params =  {
            UserAttributes: [
              {
                  Name: 'custom:sillyName',
                  Value: 'customSillyName'
              }
            ],
            UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
            Username: event.userName
        }

        cognitoIdServiceProvider.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        }); 

        callback(null,event);

};
```

Note if you attempt to user `cognitoIdServiceProvider.adminUpdateUserAttributes` in the preSignUp trigger hook you;ll get an exception saying the user does not exit yet

Comment: Nope. I have tested both Pre Signup and Post Confirmation triggers and in both cases the error message is `"errorMessage": "User does not exist."` At both of these stages, the user apparently is still not created in the pool because of which the attributes can't be updated using the SDK APIs. Injecting updated Attributes to `event.request.userAttributes` in pre signup trigger also doesn't seem to work. The only thing that can be done is validation type stuff and other things like logging etc.

Comment: I found this to work for a Post Auth trigger with a slight adjustment, I needed to move the `callback(null, event)` into the `cognitoIdServiceProvider.adminUpdateUserAttributes()` callback function.

Answer (score 5):

To fill in some detail around @Khoi's very helpful answer, and for all you cut-and-pasters (you know who you are), here is a template for a Lambda that runs off a Cognito User Pool Post Confirmation trigger.

The Lambda sets a new value in a user's custom attribute, which is "fruit" in this example.  Here are some gotchas to avoid in the implementation minefield:

1. The custom attribute must be defined in the user pool at the time you create the user pool, and you must set the attribute ***Mutable*** when you define it.
2. After deploying the Lambda to your AWS account, you need to point the Post confirmation trigger to this Lambda through the User Pools configuration pages in the AWS console.
   *Services->Cognito->Manage User Pools->Your User Pools->Triggers->Post Confirmation*
3. The Lambda needs permission to update the User Pool attributes, which is accomplished by attaching an IAM policy to the Lambda that allows "cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes" action.  See example below.
4. You access the attribute with the prefix ***custom:*** as in *custom:fruit*  .
5. The colon in the custom attribute makes Javascript unhappy, so when accessing the custom attribute in a client from a CognitoUser object e.g. from the Amplify signIn() method you need to use
   `let a = user.attributes['custom:fruit']`

### Sample Lambda

```
    const aws = require('aws-sdk');
    const cisProvider = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18' });

    // Cognito User Pool Lambda triggers are documented here:
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html
    exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {

        const params = {
            UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
            Username: event.userName,
            UserAttributes:  // this parameter needs to be an array
                [
                    {
                        Name: 'custom:fruit',
                        Value: 'banana'
                    }
                ]
        };

        if (event.request.userAttributes.email) {
            try {
                await cisProvider
                    .adminUpdateUserAttributes(params)
                    .promise();

                console.log('Success');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error', error);
            }
        }

        callback(null, event);
    };
```

### SAM YAML template

If you are using AWS SAM (as I hope you are) to debug and deploy your Lambda, here is a template for this Lambda.  Note the ***Role*** resource.  Before deploying the Lambda you will need to define this IAM role in the AWS console.  There probably is a way to define the role right here in the template, but I'm not that expert with AWS YAML.  Deploy the Lambda to your AWS account with  the SAM CLI command
`sam deploy --guided`

```
  AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
  Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
  Description: >
    SAM Template for lambda function that runs as a Cognito User Pool post confirmation trigger.
    Cognito invokes this function when a new user signs up.
    
  Globals:
    Function:
      Timeout: 3

  Resources:
    PostConfirmationFunction:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
        CodeUri: post-confirmation/
        Handler: app.lambdaHandler
        Runtime: nodejs14.x
        Role:
          # This role gives Lambda permission to update user pool attributes as well as basic execution.
          arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/lambda-cognito-update-role

  Outputs:
    PostConfirmationFunction:
      Description: "Post Confirmation Lambda Function ARN"
      Value: !GetAtt PostConfirmationFunction.Arn
```

### IAM Role

You need to create a role in the IAM console that includes permission to update user attributes.  I prefer to do this with an "inline policy" to avoid a proliferation of IAM policies in my account with unclear dependency.  The best way I have found to do this is a two step process:

1. Create a role in the IAM console with the same name listed in the YAML template, *lambda-cognito-update-role* in this example.  Attach the AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole in the *Permissions* step, and give it the the role name *lambda-cognito-update-role*.
2. In the IAM section of the AWS console, under Roles, find your newly created role and click to open it.

   - While you're in here, copy the role ARN from the top of the Summary page into your SAM YAML template.
   - Click ***Add inline policy*** on the right, click the JSON tab, and overwrite the boilerplate with the JSON below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "CognitoUpdate",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Arguably the resource should be more specific, limited only to user pools in your account maybe.  I leave that to your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse. You need to use AWS SDK.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('./config'); 

function updateAttribute(params) {
    AWS.config.update({
        'region' : config.AWSConfig.region,
        'accessKeyId': config.AWSConfig.accessKeyId,
        'secretAccessKey': config.AWSConfig.secretAccessKey
    });
    let cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    let parameters = { UserPoolId : config.userPoolDetails.userPoolId,
    Username : params.userName,
    UserAttributes : [
        {
            'Name': params.nameOfAttribute ,
            'Value': params.newValueOfAttribute
        },
    ]}
    
    cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminUpdateUserAttributes(parameters,function (err, result) {
        if(err)
        console.log(err);
        else
        console.log("Attribute updated successfully");
    })
}

let params = {
    userName : 'username',
    nameOfAttribute : 'name',
    newValueOfAttribute : 'Sachin'
}

updateAttribute(params);
```

You can even add new attribute like this.

You can read more here :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html

Answer (score 0):

My use case was to add extra information into the signInUserSession:idToken so I didnt have to do an extra query in my backend to get this specific piece of data but just get it from the IDToken.
After reviewing the answers, I found a solution in the AWS docs that works:
`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-token-generation-example-1`

So this Pretoken generation event works for me:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('event', event)
    event.response = {
    claimsOverrideDetails: {
      claimsToAddOrOverride: {
        my_first_attribute: "first_value",
        my_second_attribute: "second_value",
        'custom:newEmail': 'foo'
      },
      claimsToSuppress: ["email"],
    },
  };

  return event;
};
```

The `custom:newEmail` is an existing custom attribute which was changed after logging in with Cognito, but the my_first_attribute attribute was not registered in Cognito and also showed up in my idToken.

So that is great!