# Update AWS Cognito user's custom attributes without logging user in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a new project where I'm for the first time using both Vue js and AWS Cognito. I'm finding cognito documentation difficult to find, or simply missing.

Within the Vue application I'm using Amplify to handle all the user management which is working fine.

In my user pool, I added 2 custom attributes:

- custom:first_name
- custom:last_name

From within the Vue application, I post a quote request to a .net core api which contains all kinds of details, along with the logged in user's cognito username and a first name and last name:

```
{
    "details": "all kinds of quote details",
    "user": {
        "cognitoUsername": "fd17f624-cf31-11e9-904a-88d7f67d5c52",
        "firstName": "Carel",
        "lastName": "Nel"
    }
}
```

Using the `Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication` library, I am able to query the cognito user record with all it's attributes:

```
cognitoUser = await _pool.FindByIdAsync(model.User.CognitoUsername);
```

Next, my plan is to update the `custom:first_name` and `custom:last_name` attributes in the pool from this API post method after all kinds of other validation checks have passed. If I try the update, I get the following error:

```
if (attributesChanged)
{
    await cognitoUser.UpdateAttributesAsync(userAttributes);
    // Error: "Database Failure - User is not authenticated."
}
```

To test this a bit, I tried the following, which then worked:

```
if (attributesChanged)
{
    await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(cognitoUser, "password", false, false);
    await cognitoUser.UpdateAttributesAsync(userAttributes);
}
```

So, if I sign in the user with the password, I'm able to update the custom attributes in the cognito pool successfully. I don't want to have to do this, however. Is there some kind of admin user configuration I can set up on the API that would allow me to update the user pools records without the specific user being logged in, or can I (should I) pass some the jwt token for the logged in user from the Vue application to the API and somehow use this to ensure authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope for an app client. You should then be able to modify the user attributes via that user.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html

Check the "Allowed OAuth Scopes" section about the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope.

Comment: I do indeed have the  `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` set for the cognito app client I'm using from within the API, but its still requiring that the user itself is logged in on the API

Comment: sorry for not able to help you, but according to this question, looks like you can use the SDK to update the user attributes.  check the answer by the user @Khoi, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487237/is-it-possible-to-modify-aws-cognito-user-attributes-in-the-lambda-triggers